# Login form in ASP.net does not work

Tags: sql, asp.net, forms, redirect, authentication

I'm new to ASP.net and currently failing to create a simple functioning login form. After establishing the connection to my database, I wanted the function to check whether a given combination of username and password exists in the database. Due to the fact that I have not created the "member zone" page yet, It's supposed to do nothing if the data is valid and return "Login failed" in the opposite case. For some reason, it doesn't work. I would be glad if someone could help me trace the problem.

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new 
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ToString());
    string query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + UserName.Text + 
"' AND password='" + Password.Text + "' ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    string output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    if (output == "1")
    {
        //Creating a session for the user
        Session["user"] = UserName.Text;
        Response.Redirect("");
    }
    else
        Response.Write("Login failed.");

}
```

Comment: What is the error. You should use debugger to find out.

Comment: There is no error, but the page merely reloads itself without anything else happening.

Comment: You should do research on parameratized queries and sql injection. Your code is vulnerable as it is now.

Comment: I know it's terribly vulnerable, but it's a school project, so the standards are quite low.

Comment: @UriSteiff No, the standards are not so low. You are in school to *learn* how to do things the right way. When someone points out the right way and you say "that's not important" that means you don't want to take the time to learn the correct way. What happens when you get outside an academic setting? You're not going to know how to do the right way. Learn security now where screwing up doesn't hurt anyone. Parameterize your queries, and don't store plaintext passwords in the database. They should be one way hashed and salted.

Comment: My intention was not that I have no interest in improving my skills and my code. It's just that I have a short period until the final deadline. After liberating myself from the chains of my school responsibilities, surely I will invest time and energy in learning how to do things the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You have `SELECT * FROM` in the query and you are using `ExecuteScalar` method to check if anything is returned.

You should use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM` to get the number of rows exist in the table for given username and password.

Another thing which is not right in your code is the generation of query. Using parameterized query is the most recommended approach.

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ToString());

    string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=@userName AND password=@password";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userName", UserName.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", Password.Text));
    con.Open();
    string output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    if (output == "1")
    {
        //Creating a session for the user
        Session["user"] = UserName.Text;
        Response.Redirect("");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Login failed.");
    }
```

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

***You forgot to open connection before executing ExecuteScalar()***

```
 protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ToString());

string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=@userName AND password=@password";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userName", UserName.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", Password.Text));

//Add Below line and test your code.
con.Open();

string output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

if (output == "1")
{
    //Creating a session for the user
    Session["user"] = UserName.Text;
    Response.Redirect("");
}
else
{
    Response.Write("Login failed.");
}
```